# Outlook 2016: Add-In appears only in Outlook Web Access and not in Desktop Outlook

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

Our Company wants to develop an Add-In for Outlook 2016 and use the new web technology. As a first step we created the Manifest-XML and put the resources to a server. Then we did the following:

- We imported the manifest in the Exchange Admin Center for the whole organization from the harddisk.
- The Add-In was activated for an account.

The result: In the Outlook variant for the web OWA the buttons appeared together with the task pane. In Outlook for the Desktop however the buttons were missing in the ribbon and also the task pane, although the add-in appeared in the settings.

For testing reasons we got the web-add-in "Wunderlist" from the Store and this worked.

Here the Manifest (still in development):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--Created:cb85b80c-f585-40ff-8bfc-12ff4d0e34a9-->
<OfficeApp
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
  xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>7164e750-dc86-49c0-b548-1bac57abdc7c</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Microsoft Outlook Dev Center</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Add-in Command Demo" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Adds command buttons to the ribbon in Outlook"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Samples/XPages/xScrapbook.nsf/assets/icon128.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Samples/XPages/xScrapbook.nsf/assets/icon128.png" />

  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.google.de" />

  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="MailBox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <!-- These elements support older clients that don't support add-in commands -->
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <!-- NOTE: Just reusing the read taskpane page that is invoked by the button
             on the ribbon in clients that support add-in commands. You can 
             use a completely different page if desired -->
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://www.google.de"/>
        <RequestedHeight>450</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">

    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>

    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

          <!-- Message read form -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadDemoGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />

                <!-- Task pane button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="green-icon-16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="green-icon-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="green-icon-80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="readTaskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>

              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>

    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <!-- Blue icon -->
        <bt:Image id="blue-icon-16" DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Samples/XPages/xScrapbook.nsf/assets/icon-16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="blue-icon-32" DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Samples/XPages/xScrapbook.nsf/assets/icon-32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="blue-icon-80" DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Samples/XPages/xScrapbook.nsf/assets/icon-80.png" />
        <!-- Red icon -->
        <bt:Image id="red-icon-16" DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Samples/XPages/xScrapbook.nsf/assets/icon-16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="red-icon-32" DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Samples/XPages/xScrapbook.nsf/assets/icon-32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="red-icon-80" DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Samples/XPages/xScrapbook.nsf/assets/icon-80.png" />
        <!-- Green icon -->
        <bt:Image id="green-icon-16" DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Samples/XPages/xScrapbook.nsf/assets/icon-16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="green-icon-32" DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Samples/XPages/xScrapbook.nsf/assets/icon-32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="green-icon-80" DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Samples/XPages/xScrapbook.nsf/assets/icon-80.png" />
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="https://www.google.de" />
        <bt:Url id="readTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Source/ARC/ARCS_40_DEDE_SRC.NSF/CWEB_CONTENT_XC_DIAE.xsp?Addin" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Add-in Demo" />
        <bt:String id="funcReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Get subject" />
        <bt:String id="menuReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Get property" />
        <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Display all properties" />

        <bt:String id="funcReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Gets the subject of the message or appointment" />
        <bt:String id="menuReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Choose a property to get" />
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Get all properties" />

        <bt:String id="menuItem1ReadLabel" DefaultValue="Get item class" />
        <bt:String id="menuItem2ReadLabel" DefaultValue="Get date time created" />
        <bt:String id="menuItem3ReadLabel" DefaultValue="Get item ID" />
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="funcReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Gets the subject of the message or appointment and displays it in the info bar. This is an example of a function button." />
        <bt:String id="menuReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Gets the selected property of the message or appointment and displays it in the info bar. This is an example of a drop-down menu button." />
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties of the message or appointment. This is an example of a button that opens a task pane." />

        <bt:String id="menuItem1ReadTip" DefaultValue="Gets the item class of the message or appointment and displays it in the info bar." />
        <bt:String id="menuItem2ReadTip" DefaultValue="Gets the date and time the message or appointment was created and displays it in the info bar." />
        <bt:String id="menuItem3ReadTip" DefaultValue="Gets the item ID of the message or appointment and displays it in the info bar." />
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

It would be nice to get a hint, why the web-add-in does not work in Outlook 2016 for the Windows-Desktop. Thanks in advance

**Update**: I am using the following version of Outlook

Microsoft Outlook 2016 MSO (16.0.4266.1001) 64-Bit

Comment: What version of Outlook (including build) are you using?

Comment: Accepting Answers: [How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest there are following lines define add-in images ...

```
<IconUrl DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Samples/XPages/xScrapbook.nsf/assets/icon128.png" />
<HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Samples/XPages/xScrapbook.nsf/assets/icon128.png" />
```

I assume (by looking at the image name) the actual image size is 128x128 and this image is set for both [`IconUrl`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/iconurl) and [`HighResolutionIconUrl`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/highresolutioniconurl). This is incorrect and will/may cause the issues in Outlook desktop. The images for `HighResolutionIconUrl` will be fine at 128x128, but cannot be used for `IconUrl`. Read documentation through and specify the image sizes required. The following is the quote from documentation ...

- `IconUrl` - The image must be in one of the following file formats: GIF, JPG, PNG, EXIF, BMP or TIFF. For content and task pane apps, the image specified must be 32 x 32 pixels.
- `HighResolutionIconUrl` - The image must be in one of the following file formats at a recommended resolution of 64 x 64 pixels: GIF, JPG, PNG, EXIF, BMP or TIFF.